# vim 8 packages on linux

Tags: vimrc, packages

I'm running Vim 8 on Linux and I would like to use packages, but I have a few questions.

Between the following directories, where do I create the `~/.vim/pack` directory?

- system vimrc
- user vimrc
- 2nd user vimrc
- user exrc file
- defaults file

---

**UPDATE**: I am totally confused. I am wanting to do two things. I want to be able to edit my vimrc so that I can do things like set options. When I run `vim --version` I get.

- system vimrc: `$VIM/vimrc`  ---? what does `$VIM` mean?
- user vimrc: `$HOME/.vimrc`  ---? what does `$HOME` mean?
- do I create these? I assume this is home directory for vim not my linux system.
- what do I need to do or understand in order to work with the vimrc file.

The second thing that I want to do is be able to use plug ins or packages in vim 8
what do I do to have this working?

Comment: Hello and welcome to [vi.se]! I'm having some trouble understanding your question... Becase `~/.vim/` is already a directory, a directory named `.vim` directly under your home directory (that's what `~` means in Vim, in your shell, etc.) So you should simply `mkdir -p ~/.vim/pack` to create that directory. On the other hand, the "directories" you listed (vimrc, exrc or defaults files) are all actually *files* and not directories. How are they related? Please edit the question to add more details on what you're trying to accomplish! Thanks!

Comment: I have converted your answer to an edit, since it's a follow up to your original question.

Comment: I'm reading your question again and it's still unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish here... Yes your vimrc is a file named `.vimrc` under your home directory, or `$HOME`, or `~`. Just create a file by that name and Vim will find it and read it during startup. Maybe you should look for Vim tutorials online? You should post questions here when you have a specific question to ask, a specific task to accomplish. If you do have one, please rephrase the question (or post a new one), please make it as specific as you can!

Comment: Also *try* some things first and see where they work and where they fail. Just seeing that by yourself should help you understand how they work. And it should help you narrow down which parts don't make sense to you yet. At that point, do some research on those, see what you can find on Google, on Vim's help system, etc. And then when you're still stuck ask questions here. You're more likely to be able to explain your question very well when you do, and you should get good answers then.